# What are scroll/jump (navigation) links in html pages?

Tags: html, scroll, hyperlink, navigation

I am talking about links that starts with `#` in address-bar. In Wikipedia is is common that this type links provides feature to scroll/jump/navigate in webpage.

Example: [Free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) article on Wikipedia contains this type of link on contents e.g. [Definition and the Four Freedoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software#Definition_and_the_Four_Freedoms) directly scrolls/jumps to that topic. So, I want to know what are this type of links and how they works?

Note: I've some basic knowledge about html and know that with anchor tag `<a>` we can links the web-address but no idea about this type of links that works in a page. Seems like constants provided address?

---

Another question is while reading [this](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/categories.html) page I've tried (according to heading of various points) to add `#freeware` in address-bar and surprised to see [that](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/categories.html#freeware) working! (because there is no link provided in page for that scrolls/jumps like that of Wikipedia)

So, Is this works with text starting with (which I think not) or headings might be inter-linked (which I think).

---

Thus, I want to know What are this type of html links that features scroll/jump/navigate within page? & How they are working?

Comment: *Requesting for correction (if any) in title or tagging of my post.*

Comment: This is quite a broad question, and possibly not the appropriate place to ask it.. but essentially these tags refer to a uniquely identified element in the DOM, by giving it the <x id=""> attribute. When your browser is pointed to it, it will jump straight to it. It can also be used by JavaScript and CSS to locate specific elements.

Comment: You are looking for [Fragments](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#scroll-to-fragid) as used on the [`<a> element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) and [Fragment link not working](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9787398/578411) could be a close enough duplicate...